# Wordpress - Navigation Sub Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I think I have an easy one to fix here but I've been looking at it for too long and can no longer see through the weeds.

I've added a navigation bar to a custom Wordpress theme. The parent elements work fine but the sub menu items are not display as they should.

Sub Menu items are not displaying below the parent element, and then each subsequent child is being displayed in a horizontal line. I have tried adding `display:inline-block` etc to the child `li` elements but still can not get it to display correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Jack

**Navigation CSS**

```
.nav-main {width:50%; float:right;}
.nav-main ul {text-align:right; font-size:18px; padding-top:35px;}
.nav-main ul li {display:inline-block; margin-left:15px;}
.nav-main ul li a {color:#666; text-decoration:none;}
.nav-main ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; } 

.nav-main ul ul li {z-index: 1000; position: absolute; background: white;}

.nav-main ul ul li a {padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 10000;  }

.nav-main ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

**Navigation HTML**

```
 <header>
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="logo"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logo.png" id="logo-img" /></a></div>
                <nav class="nav-main">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main-menu' )); ?>   
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
 <header>
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="logo"><a href="website.co.uk"><img src="website.co.uk/logo.png" id="logo-img" /></a></div>
                <nav class="nav-main">
                    <div class="menu-menu-main-container"><ul id="menu-menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-138"><a href="http://website.co.uk/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14005"><a href="website.co.uk">About</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-14013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14013"><a href="website.co.uk">Our Staff</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1699" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1699"><a href="website.co.uk">Parents</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="website.co.uk">Curriculum</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="website.co.uk">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div> 
                </nav>
                   </div>
        </header>
```

[Image of Nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPJd7.png)

Comment: Why are you using absolute positionning on your secondary `<ul>`s and `<li>`s ? Absolute positionning (if you must use it) should be set only on the `<ul>` and not on his children. It looks like you have padding and or margins interfering as well. Try and recreate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) either as a code snippet or on JSFiddle to see what's the issue.

Comment: _“Navigation HTML”_, `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main-menu' )); ?>` - see how those two don’t match? This is a client-side problem, so please post the actual rendered HTML in such a case. People should not need to set up a full WP instance to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. Will take a look at this.

Comment: @04FS added the rendered HTML. Thanks

Comment: @JackSmith Did you tried to replace the below code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `position:absolute` to the submenu then the parent menu `li` should be `position:relative`. Replace your Code with this:

```css
.nav-main {width:100%; float:right;}
.nav-main ul {text-align:right; font-size:18px; padding-top:35px;}
.nav-main ul li {display:inline-block; margin-left:15px;position:relative;}
.nav-main ul li a {color:#666; text-decoration:none;}
.nav-main ul ul {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;

}

.nav-main ul ul li {
    background: grey;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-main ul ul li a {
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-main ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

```html
 <header>
            <div class="inner">
                <nav class="nav-main">
                    <div class="menu-menu-main-container"><ul id="menu-menu-main" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-77 current_page_item menu-item-138"><a href="http://website.co.uk/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-14005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-14005"><a href="website.co.uk">About</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-14013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14013"><a href="website.co.uk">Our Staff</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1699" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1699"><a href="website.co.uk">Parents</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="website.co.uk">Curriculum</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="website.co.uk">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div> 
                </nav>
                   </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why this will fix the error - it's not very helpful to code dump.

Comment: Agreed with @coops, check out [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I tried adding it and doesn't look quite right. https://imgur.com/a/tJFo1Nd

Comment: 1 sub menu at the moment. But there will be more added in the future. I've added the rendered HTML if that helps. Thanks

Comment: @JackSmith please check now the code is modified and I have used `grey background` to show you.

Comment: and also please `.nav-main {width:100%; float:right;}` replace width to `50%` as per your design.